# Restore deleted Openshift application

Tags: openshift

I've accidentally deleted PHP application, running on Openshift. The backups was made long time ago and I can't seem to find a way to contact the Openshift support team to help me with this. Is there any way to restore the deleted application?

Comment: @JoãoGonçalves thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately OpenShift Online does not keep user-accessible backups.  According to the ToS, application backups are the users responsibility.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this question and the unexpected success in restoring the data motivated a few people using OpenShift Online current gen (v2) to contact us with false hopes. However, we do not keep separate user data backups that could be simply restored. This is indeed user's responsibility as mentioned in comments above.

The above described situation, where we were able to catch the backup and isolate the respective application, was a mere coincidence with a good timing. In 99% of cases, we will have to disappoint you and recommend re-deploying the app from your source code.
It's likely, that if you have lost your precious data, you'll try the luck anyway by contacting us. This is just to set the success expectations...

---

I'm aware that this is not a good advice in case you have come here already, but anyway... Please have a look on [how to create backup snapshots](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/backing-up-applications.html) of your applications to prevent situations like this in future.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Jiri from the Customer Success Team, another guy from the Operations team send me a daily backup of my application which I then managed to restore.

Great support and great team! Many thanks =)